# Work with interface but keep concrete values

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to make a function that works with a list of an interface but I would like to keep the concrete class values for those lists. For example:

```
public interface GUID_OBJECT
{
    string GUID { get; set; }
}

public class Car : GUID_OBJECT
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string CarSpecifikProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bike : GUID_OBJECT
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string BikeSpecifikProp { get; set; }
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>() { new Car() { GUID = "1", CarSpecifikProp = "carstuff" }, new Car() { GUID = "2", CarSpecifikProp = "carsuff" } };
        var bikes = new List<Bike>() { new Bike() { GUID = "1", BikeSpecifikProp = "bikestuff" }, new Bike() { GUID = "2", BikeSpecifikProp = "bikestuff" } };

        var filteredCars = FilterGuidObjects(cars);

        foreach (var car in filteredCars)
        {
            car.CarSpecifikProp = "changethis";
        }

        var filteredBikes = FilterGuidObjects(bikes);

        foreach (var bike in filteredBikes)
        {
            bike.BikeSpecifikProp = "changethis";
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<GUID_OBJECT> FilterGuidObjects(List<GUID_OBJECT> objects)
    {
        return objects.Where(x => x.GUID == "1").ToList();
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work but it illustrates what I would like to do. I have a web api project that returns various type of lists of objects, but all these objects have some things in common such as `GUID` for example. Can I write functions that work with the interface `GUID_OBJECT` but keep the `Car` and `Bike` specific properties after that function returns its List of `GUID_OBJECT` interfaces? How would you deal with a scenario like this?

Comment: Those are not "GUID"s

Comment: using an interface as a interface to classes of different types doesn't destroy the non interface values you just need to re convert them to access them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make a generic method with a constraint:

```
static List<G> FilterGuidObjects<G>(List<G> objects) where G: GUID_OBJECT
{
    return objects.Where(x => x.GUID == "1").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of interfaces is to have only the common properties of the classes that implement them. If you need to use a specific property you'll need to cast to the type you want:

```
var obj = (MyType) myInterface
```

Since you're working with lists, you can cast the entire list like this:

```
listOfInterface.Cast<MyType>().ToList()
```

Comment: i would suggest a var obj = myInterface as MyType. also OfType<T> instead of Cast as they don't error if they type is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing FilterGuidObjects as a generic function:

```
        static List<T> FilterGuidObjects<T>(List<T> objects) where T : GUID_OBJECT
        {
            return objects.Where(x => x.GUID == "1").ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of achieving this but the crux of the matter is you have to convert the interface back to the original type

Method 1: generic filter on the function

```
static List<T> FilterGuidObjects(List<T> objects)
    :where T:GUID_OBJECT
{
    return objects.Where(x => x.GUID == "1").ToList();
}
```

Pros Quick and simple, will even infer the type automatically 
Cons you can't feed in a Mixed list

Method 2 Type Filter the collection

```
var filteredCars = FilterGuidObjects(MixedListOfVechiles).OfType<Car>();
```

Pros Can handle mixed lists
Con have to specify the conversion every time

Method 3 Convert the Type Directly

```
var car = guid_object as Car
if(car != null)
    car.CarSpecifikProp = "changethis";
```

or

```
if(guid_object is Car)
{
    var car = (Car)guid_object
    car.CarSpecifikProp = "changethis";
}
```

Pros doesn't use generics
Con requires lots of code